# How to create Android app based on Angular2 app.

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I created medium large Angular2 app a few weeks ago. It's full responsive, so I wanted to make Android application based on my application. The problem is that my app, (as standard Android WebView) is loaded too long (about 10 seconds).

I heard of that Android WebView has a problem with render javascripts, thence such a long time of loading app. Is it true? Can someone explain me this?

Searching the internet, I found information about some tools: NativeScript, Cordova and Ionic. Someone can tell me if these tools will help me with my problem?

Comment: Do you have some pages that have a lot of data?

Comment: Ionic2 and Cordova uses Webview but Nativescript (+ Angular2) uses native views/elements

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy no. App size is about 1,5MB. All of css are downloaded from CDN. Application loading time is 1-2 seconds in browser. The problem is only for WebView.

Comment: @MarekMaszay so, using NativeScript can help me?

Comment: Probably but you will have to rewrite some view files maybe little controllers but you can have native app with ng2 base code

Answer (score 3):

NativeScript is a solution providing you with direct access to iOS and Android APIs and at the same time has exposed some standard layouts and modules which are easily recognised by web developers. In combination with Angular-2 the experience is almost like developing a web app, however, keep in mind that there is no DOM and there are some specific rules to follow when creating an app for the mobile universe.

For more details what NativeScript can and can't do I would recommend taking a look at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWM-_majn0E) and going through [this tutorial](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1.html) step by step.

Comment: Fixed the link - you can also take a look at the community videos - some of them are really good https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nativescript+angular+2